# JavaScript variable scope in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've got the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<p id="p"></p>

<script>

var top = 9;
( function () {  top += 1;  document.getElementById( "p" ).innerHTML = top;  } )()

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

It works fine in Internet Explorer ( prints 10 ), but in Google Chrome it prints [object Window].
But if i change it like this:

```
( function () {  var top = 9; top += 1; document.getElementById( "p" ).innerHTML = top; } )()
```

it works in Chrome fine too. The only change is that the variable is now local. Does it mean that in Chrome i can't access global variables? Whatever i do i can't get the right result..

Comment: Don't use global variables.

Comment: `window.top` is an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your variable name, as it's conflicting with the `Window.top` global object. See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.top) doc page

Comment: I had the same issue with a variable named `status`. Learned the hard way lol

Comment: These name conflicts seem really unconvinient. That's the big disadvatage of javascript and other such languages i think..  In Java language there are no such problems for example

Comment: Of course there are. Every try to assign a reserved word in Java?

Comment: That's just reserved words :)  There are little bit of them and you can remember almost all of them since they're commonly used.  But in other languages there are many such "hidden" words, which you don't know about. And it's just unconvinient to have one big global namespace

Comment: @AlexOswald and that's precisely why your second function works - it's because it is NOT in the global namespace. There are two namespaces - global and function, it's advisable to not use global for the precise reason you saw.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode should prevent this kind of thing. And the other thing about reserved words is that they tend to be highlighted in any decent editor, whereas things like `top` do not.